# Clarification on the proof of $\pi$ being transcendental.

Tags: abstract-algebra, pi, transcendental-numbers

I was reading a proof on the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental and the author mentioned that

> The $\alpha_i$ satisfy a polynomial equation over $\mathbb{Q}$ so their elementary symmetric functions are rational. Hence the elementary symmetric functions of the sums of pairs are symmetric functions of the $\alpha_i$ and are also rational.

I'm not quite sure why the elementary symmetric functions of the sums of pairs are rational given that the elementary symmetric functions of the $\alpha_i$ are rational. For instance, the 2nd elementary symmetric function of the sum of pairs contains $\alpha_i^2$, and how can we deal with these terms?

EDIT: The proof can be found here: https://sixthform.info/maths/files/pitrans.pdf (Theorem 4).

Comment: The elementary symmetric functions of the sums of pairs are also symmetric functions of the $\alpha_i$s.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not following but I thought the elementary symmetric function is given by $$e_k = \sum \prod_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots i_k \leq n} \alpha_{i_1},$$ in which there is no $\alpha_i^2$?

Comment: There's a theorem  stating that elementary symmetric functions  generate all symmetric (polynomial)  functions as an algebra. For details, see [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Answer (score 2):

The author is using the [fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials), according to which the $A$-subalgebra of $A[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$ generated by the $n$ elementary symmetric polynomials is the ring of symmetric polynomials with coefficients in $A$ (in this case, it's $A=\Bbb Z$ or, at worst, $\Bbb Q$).